# Using cloudant-sync as backend for java desktop app

Tags: java, synchronization, cloudant

I downloaded the cloudant-sync prebuilt jars (core and jse only) from mavin repo and attached both as library to my idea project, then ran the project but encountered the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Exception in Application start method Caused by:
>  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/almworks/sqlite4java/SQLiteException.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some of dependancies from your classpath. If you are using gradle make sure the following is present in your dependencies block:

```
compile group: 'com.cloudant', name: 'cloudant-sync-datastore-javase', version:'2.0.0'
```

Comment: I'm neither using gradle nor mavin. how do I determine the missing dependencies?

Comment: Firstly I'd highly advise you to use maven / gradle / some kind of build tool that does this for you, otherwise download the jar from: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/cloudant/cloudant-sync-datastore-javase/2.0.0/ it will work with the jar you've already added

Comment: I've already added that jar as library, I mentioned it in the question. Meanwhile I will try gradle and see how it goes. I'm most grateful for your attention.

Comment: Sorry I mis-read, you need this the jar for this gradle dependency `compile group: 'com.almworks.sqlite4java', name: 'sqlite4java', version: '1.0.392'`

Comment: I have tried without success to include gradle support in my javafx project. Know any step by step guide on how to do this?

Comment: I'm now using maven.